# Mvn install with surefire.debug results in ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use?

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm able to run my application fine with no errors with

```
mvn install
```

However when I try to enable remote debugging with

```
mvn install -Dmaven.surefire.debug
```

I get this error

```
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [open/src/jdk.jdwp.agent/share/native/libjdwp/debugInit.c:734]
```

I understand that surefire uses port 5005. At the time of an error, I do see a process running on port 5005, but that was the process that was kicked off by the command itself

```
  l@mac target % lsof -i tcp:5005

COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    35842   267u  IPv4 0x8763e5d80030efe5      0t0  TCP localhost:avt-profile-2 (LISTEN)
```

After exiting the mvn install command, I see that there's no process running on port 5005.

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue? Is there another port involved here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I needed to disable forking - https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/debugging.html

Passing it as a command line argument didn't work for me. I had to also specify it in the pom file